# Optgroup in DropDownlistFor MVC 4 Not Support Mvc validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownGroupListFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, IEnumerable<GroupedSelectListItem> selectList, string defaultText, object htmlAttributes, bool isDisabled)
    {
        if (isDisabled)
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributeMerge = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
            htmlAttributeMerge.Add("disabled", "disabled");

            return DropDownGroupListFor(htmlHelper,expression, selectList, defaultText, htmlAttributeMerge);
        }
        else
        {
            return DropDownGroupListFor(htmlHelper, expression, selectList, defaultText, htmlAttributes);
        }
    }
    // Helper methods

    private static IEnumerable<GroupedSelectListItem> GetSelectData(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name)
    {
        object o = null;
        if (htmlHelper.ViewData != null)
        {
            o = htmlHelper.ViewData.Eval(name);
        }
        if (o == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                String.Format(
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                    "Missing Select Data",
                    name,
                    "IEnumerable<GroupedSelectListItem>"));
        }
        IEnumerable<GroupedSelectListItem> selectList = o as IEnumerable<GroupedSelectListItem>;
        if (selectList == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                String.Format(
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                    "Wrong Select DataType",
                    name,
                    o.GetType().FullName,
                    "IEnumerable<GroupedSelectListItem>"));
        }
        return selectList;
    }

    internal static string ListItemToOption(GroupedSelectListItem item)
    {
        TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("option")
        {
            InnerHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.Text)
        };
        if (item.Value != null)
        {
            builder.Attributes["value"] = item.Value;
        }
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            builder.Attributes["selected"] = "selected";
        }
        return builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
    }

    private static MvcHtmlString SelectInternal(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string optionLabel, string name, IEnumerable<GroupedSelectListItem> selectList, bool allowMultiple, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        name = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Null Or Empty", "name");
        }

        bool usedViewData = false;

        // If we got a null selectList, try to use ViewData to get the list of items.
        if (selectList == null)
        {
            selectList = GetSelectData(htmlHelper, name);
            usedViewData = true;
        }

        object defaultValue = (allowMultiple) ? htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(name, typeof(string[])) : htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(name, typeof(string));

        // If we haven't already used ViewData to get the entire list of items then we need to
        // use the ViewData-supplied value before using the parameter-supplied value.
        if (!usedViewData)
        {
            if (defaultValue == null)
            {
                defaultValue = htmlHelper.ViewData.Eval(name);
            }
        }

        if (defaultValue != null)
        {
            IEnumerable defaultValues = (allowMultiple) ? defaultValue as IEnumerable : new[] { defaultValue };
            IEnumerable<string> values = from object value in defaultValues select Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            HashSet<string> selectedValues = new HashSet<string>(values, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            List<GroupedSelectListItem> newSelectList = new List<GroupedSelectListItem>();

            foreach (GroupedSelectListItem item in selectList)
            {
                item.Selected = (item.Value != null) ? selectedValues.Contains(item.Value) : selectedValues.Contains(item.Text);
                newSelectList.Add(item);
            }
            selectList = newSelectList;
        }

        // Convert each ListItem to an <option> tag
        StringBuilder listItemBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // Make optionLabel the first item that gets rendered.
        if (optionLabel != null)
        {
            listItemBuilder.AppendLine(ListItemToOption(new GroupedSelectListItem() { Text = optionLabel, Value = String.Empty, Selected = false }));
        }

        foreach (var group in selectList.GroupBy(i => i.GroupKey))
        {
            string groupName = selectList.Where(i => i.GroupKey == group.Key).Select(it => it.GroupName).FirstOrDefault();
            listItemBuilder.AppendLine(string.Format("<optgroup label=\"{0}\" value=\"{1}\">", groupName, group.Key));
            foreach (GroupedSelectListItem item in group)
            {
                listItemBuilder.AppendLine(ListItemToOption(item));
            }
            listItemBuilder.AppendLine("</optgroup>");
        }

        TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("select")
        {
            InnerHtml = listItemBuilder.ToString()
        };
        foreach (var htmlAttribute in htmlAttributes)
        {
            tagBuilder.MergeAttribute(
               htmlAttribute.Key.Replace('_', '-'),
               (string)htmlAttribute.Value
            );
        }
        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", name, true /* replaceExisting */);
        tagBuilder.GenerateId(name);
        if (allowMultiple)
        {
            tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("multiple", "multiple");
        }

        // If there are any errors for a named field, we add the css attribute.
        ModelState modelState;
        if (htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(name, out modelState))
        {
            if (modelState.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                tagBuilder.AddCssClass(HtmlHelper.ValidationInputCssClassName);
            }
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString());
    }

    internal static object GetModelStateValue(this HtmlHelper helper, string key, Type destinationType)
    {
        ModelState modelState;
        if (helper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(key, out modelState))
        {
            if (modelState.Value != null)
            {
                return modelState.Value.ConvertTo(destinationType, null /* culture */);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

> @Html.DropDownGroupListFor(m => m.id, Model.list, null, new { @class
>   = "form-control"})

this the  whole code Validation On Id But validtion not work,validation is server side when click on button to submit validtion not fire  why?

Comment: Your extension method does not add the necessary `data-val-*` attributes for client side validation (refer the [source code for SelectExtensions.cs](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs) - `tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(name, metadata));`

Comment: data-val  attribute add but required msg not show and validation not fire

Comment: No where in your code are you adding `data-val` attributes!

Comment: get some dll issue when add this method

Comment: Study the source code!!